# Add GeoJSON MultiPolygon from arrays to map

Tags: java, android

i have GeoJSON features:

sample.json:

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "value":10.529,
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     [
                        6.594247312736228,
                        46.51636675429629
                     ],
                     [
                        6.59957345109649,
                        46.511859137426164
                     ],
                     [
                        6.605031044050632,
                        46.511752830945746
                     ],
                 
                     [
                        6.594247312736228,
                        46.51636675429629
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Java:

```
PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();

        try {
            JSONObject objPolyLinesGeoJson = new JSONObject(myJson);
            String features = objPolyLinesGeoJson.get("features").toString();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(features);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JsonNode geoJsonObj = mapper.readTree(jsonObject.toString());
                ArrayNode geometryCoordinates = (ArrayNode) geoJsonObj.get("geometry").get("coordinates");

                for (JsonNode jsonNode : geometryCoordinates) {
                    // ???
                }
            }
            Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);



        } catch (Exception e) {
           //
        }
```

How to add all polygon coordinates? I don't know how to load multiple arrays in a loop. How to do this with as much optimization as possible. Do I have to make a loop within a loop? I will be grateful for any advice.

Thanks for help !